# Having Trouble Solving Next Inorder Node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am stuck on this problem. The edge case I am failing is when the given node (self) is the largest node in the tree. I would appreciate any hints to solving the problem.

The cases that I have come up with are when the right of the node is None, then I know that the solution will be grandparent or None.

Another case is when right is not None. In this case I call the right child and find the left most node because that will be the smallest node greater than the starting self node.

Given a BSTNode object, return the next in order node.

[image]

```
class BSTNode:
     def __init__(self, left, right, parent):
         self.left = left       # BSTNode
         self.right = right     # BSTNode
         self.parent = parent   # BSTNode


     def nextInorderNode(self):
```

if self was 1, return 3

if self was 3, return 4

if self was 4, return 5

if self was 9, return None

my solution:

```
class BSTNode:
    def __init__(self, left, right, parent):
        self.left = left       # BSTNode
        self.right = right     # BSTNode
        self.parent = parent   # BSTNode



def find_left_most(self):
    if (self == None):
        return self
    next = self
    while (next != None):
        if (next.left == None):
            return next
        next = next.left

def nextInorderNode(self):

    if self.right == None:
        parent = self.parent
        if (parent.left == self):
            return parent

        else:
            curr_node = parent.right 
            grand_parent = parent.parent
            return grand_parent

    else:
        child = self.right
        return child.find_left_most()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite `nextInorderNode` to walk up the tree until finding a node that `self` is to the left of, I think that will give you the result you want:

```
def nextInorderNode(self):
    if self.right is None:
        curr_node = self
        parent = curr_node.parent
        while parent and parent.left != curr_node:
            curr_node = parent
            parent = curr_node.parent
        return parent

    child = self.right
    return child.find_left_most()
```